# Filtering date on the Microsoft SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am currently using filters to filter out the data from the table by the dates where where today’s date is between the from date and the to date. And currently using the where condition as

```
Select * FROM [Snapshot].[dbo].[ABCVIEW] where (getdate() >= fromdate and (todate = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000')) or getdate() between fromdate and todate
```

There are todate which also has today's date before using any filter

[image]

but with the filter I am using I am not able to see the todate = 2016-05-31 00:00:00.000. I tried to add

```
todate<= getdate()
```

in to the filter but still no use. In the result I am not able to see today's date eg: todate = 2016-05-31 00:00:00.000 Please help with this.

Comment: Please explain in plain english what you expect the criteria to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getdate returns the current time which is greater than `2016-05-31 00:00:00.000`  so if you want to include midnight last night subtract 1 from the getdate():

```
Select * 
FROM [Snapshot].[dbo].[ABCVIEW] 
where (getdate() >= fromdate 
    and (todate = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000')) 
        or getdate()-1 between fromdate and todate
```

Answer (score 0):

if you convert to DATE you get just the date.......

```
SELECT Convert(date, getdate())
```

So you could use BETWEEN

```
.......
CONVERT( Date, fromDate) and CONVERT(Date, DateAdd(  d, 1, toDate))
```